# update the .json file key in python

Tags: python

Json file example = {"process":[{"id":0,"path":"xyz"}, {"id":1,"path":"abc"}]}

```
  with open(process_details.json,"r") as jsonfile:
      write_data= json.load(jsonfile)

  for processdetails in write_data['process']:

      Path = function_to_retreive_path(processdetails['id'])

      Write_data[processdetails]['path'] = Path

      with open("process_details.json","w") as outfile:
         json.dump(write_data,outfile)
```

As I'm trying to update the path for each process I'm able to retrieve the path but I'm unable to update it in process_details.json file. Getting the following error as unhashable type:'dict'

Can anyone advise me on this issue

Comment: The snippet is crawling with typos.

Comment: `with open(process_details.json,"r") as json` — overwriting `json` just before using it

Comment: Also look at the tool [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). You might not need python at all

Comment: Adding what `write_data` is just before dumping to the question can help us provide answers without the need to include missing functions. (`print(write_data)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json

def function_to_retreive_path (id):
    return str (id) + "_updated"

with open("process_details.json","r") as f:
    write_data = json.load(f)

for processdetails in write_data['process']:

    # debug
    print (processdetails)
    print (processdetails['id'])
    print (processdetails['path'])

    # change value
    path = function_to_retreive_path (processdetails['id'])
    processdetails['path'] = path

    # debug
    print (processdetails['path'])

with open("process_details.json","w") as outfile:
     json.dump(write_data,outfile)
```

Anyway, your error is caused by a typo. You are using Write_data with a capital W, so Python thinks, I don't know this variable, so it is no dictionary and thus not hashable.

Comment: # change the values
write_data['process'][0]['path'] = "foo"
write_data['process'][1]['path'] = "bar".   Is there a way that we could get the [0] , [1] inside a loop? Since the json is dynamic I can't hardcode the values?

Comment: right, I updated the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I can't really answer because there are some missing functions in your code so I can't run it, but the error you are facing generally means that you are using a dictionary as a key in an other dictionary.

Comment: Oh that's just a function will retrieve string you can hardcode it for testing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).